# What is the most efficient PHP accelerator for a shared hosting environment?

Tags: php, cache

Just wondering if theres any performance benefits for using something like APC over eAccelerator (for PHP) on a shared environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure about in replacement of eAccelerator, but generally APC is better to use than eAccelerator as it is more actively developed than the latter and has a much better release cycle.  Also it's probably worth pointing out that APC will be integrated as part of the core of PHP with the forthcoming PHP6 (though you'll still have to explicitly enable it in the php.ini file.) which fairly biases my mind towards it as well.

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to quantise the benefit that opcode caching will bring you without knowing much about your environment and code. Generally speaking though, you will see a performance increase of somewhere between *a little* and *a lot*, for what is very trouble on your part. So give it a go and observe your metrics.

There is a pretty good statistical comparison of opcode caches over at [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28716/which-php-opcode-cacher-should-i-use-to-improve-performance). As you'll see from the results; APC is often pipped to the post by eAccelerator in terms of performance. However performance isn't everything. APC is easy to install, configure and has good future backing - frequent releases and adoption into the PHP codebase.

Personally I use APC wherever possible.